# Rails API: params' tempfile contains null bites from upload and fails to read, but reads fine if grabbed locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, file-upload

I have a simple flow I am trying to set up in a Rails API. The business logic is already implemented and working, but I am having a problem grabbing the tempfile from the params that contains the CSV that will be uploaded via the Ember app that handles the fronted. This is my controller code:

```
def update_by_csv
  good_csv    = CSV.read("spec/fixtures/single_field_lien_update_csv.csv")
  bad_csv       = CSV.read(params[:liens_csv].tempfile)
  fields        = good_csv.first
  values        = good_csv[1..-1]
  update_data   = values.map do |row|
    lien = {}
    row.each_with_index do |val, index|
      lien[fields[index]] = val
    end
    lien
  end.map(&:symbolize_keys)

  liens = update_data.map { |lien_data| Lien.find(lien_data[:id]) }

  if columns_updateable? fields
    liens.each_with_index { |lien, i| lien.update(update_data[i]) }
    require 'pry'; binding.pry
    render json: liens, status: :accepted
  else
    # render_bad_request_for(liens)
  end
end
```

And this is the relevant test:

```
describe 'POST #update_by_csv' do
  context 'when uploading a csv with lien ids' do
    it 'can update fields via a csv' do
      payload = { liens_csv: fixture_file_upload("single_field_lien_update_csv.csv", "text/csv") }
      url = "http://api.lvh.me:3000/liens/update_by_csv.json"
      post url, payload, @subscribed_headers
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:accepted)
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the CSV being uploaded:

```
id,face_value,county_held
1,954,butts
2,2054,butts
3,9054,butts
4,42954,butts
5,29054,butts1
```

When I try to access the CSV via `CSV.read(params[:liens_csv].tempfile)`, I get the following:

```
[["id", "face_value"],
 ["1", "10314"],
 ["2", "314931"],
 ["3", "42950"],
 ["4", "3295"],
 ["5", "31059"],
 ["\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]]
```

However when it is accessed via `CSV.read("spec/fixtures/single_field_lien_update_csv.csv")` I have no issue:

```
[["id", "face_value", "county_held"],
["1", "954", "butts"],
["2", "2054", "butts"],
["3", "9054", "butts"],
["4", "42954", "butts"],
["5", "29054", "butts1"]]
```

I am unsure what exactly could be causing this within the tempfile/upload process. The file being uploaded is literally the exact same one as what is being parsed properly directly. It also may be worth noting that the CSV was generated using Ruby's CSV library for the purposes of this test so I do not believe it to be an encoding problem in that part.

Ideas? I'm truly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy your tempfile to your fixture directory and then try with exactly the same data outputed by ember?

Actually the only troubles I can imagine would be an encoding problem, \r\n return carriage, utf-8/ansi issue.

This is how I would try to fix it:

```
def update_by_csv
   good_csv    = CSV.read("spec/fixtures/single_field_lien_update_csv.csv")
   # Keep it for further informations
   File.write(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/single_field_lien_update_csv_bad.csv"), File.read(params[:liens_csv].tempfile))
   raise "STOP"
   bad_csv       = CSV.read(params[:liens_csv].tempfile)
   #...
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would fix it for sure. I am trying it right now. The `good_csv` is just an example, as it is being read from the fixtures. the `bad_csv` is the one being uploaded by `fixture_file_upload`. Ember does not actually touch this in the test suite at all, as they are kept in separate repositories. So I just use standard rails stuff to do the testing.

Problem is that even though in the params the `params[:liens_csv].tempfile` is the SAME FILE that `CSV.read("spec/fixtures/single_lien_update_csv.csv` is accessing. Yet when accessed directly its right and through params it breaks

Comment: I understand, do you send your file with multipart/form-data?